# How to install all missing dependencies in enviroment anaconda file?

Tags: python, conda

Good night! I have a .yml file with this structure:

```
name: web

channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - zope.event=4.4=py37_0
  - zope.interface=5.1.0=py37haf1e3a3_0
  - zstd=1.4.5=h41d2c2f_0
  - pip:
    - asgiref==3.2.10
    - cloudpickle==1.3.0
```

that is actually mutch bigger than this. When i run `conda env create --file ambiente.yml` i get `Solving environment: failed ResolvePackageNotFound:`   and a list of all missing dependencies. How can a install all dependencies at once?

Comment: You can move all missing packages to under `pip:` that should solve your issue. also these packages are `OSX ` specific. So if you are running it on `Linux/Windows` it will fail. The solution is to remove everything written after version number. e.g in case of `zstd=1.4.5=h41d2c2f_0` you should remove `h41d2c2f_0`  and just keep `zstd=1.4.5`

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Might the package versions be overly specific?